# How can I install Vagrant on 12.04 if ruby-json is already installed?

Tags: 12.04, apt, ruby, vagrant

I tried to install the software , which are in software center and new software like virtual box, but it is showing the error:

```
Items cannot be installed or removed until the package catalog is
repaired, do you want to repair it?
```

When I clicked the repair icon,it is showing:

```
Package operation failed, installation or removal of a software
package failed

installArchives() failed: perl: warning: Setting locale failed. perl:
warning: Please check that your locale settings:    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),   LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system. perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C"). locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to
default locale: No such file or directory locale: Cannot set
LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory locale:
Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory perl:
warning: Setting locale failed. perl: warning: Please check that your
locale settings:    LANGUAGE = (unset),     LC_ALL = (unset),   LANG =
"en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system. perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C"). locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to
default locale: No such file or directory locale: Cannot set
LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory locale:
Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory perl:
warning: Setting locale failed. perl: warning: Please check that your
locale settings:    LANGUAGE = (unset),     LC_ALL = (unset),   LANG =
"en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system. perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C"). locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to
default locale: No such file or directory locale: Cannot set
LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory locale:
Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory perl:
warning: Setting locale failed. perl: warning: Please check that your
locale settings:    LANGUAGE = (unset),     LC_ALL = (unset),   LANG =
"en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system. perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C"). locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to
default locale: No such file or directory locale: Cannot set
LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory locale:
Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
(Reading database ...  (Reading database ... 5% (Reading database ...
10% (Reading database ... 15% (Reading database ... 20% (Reading
database ... 25% (Reading database ... 30% (Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40% (Reading database ... 45% (Reading database
... 50% (Reading database ... 55% (Reading database ... 60% (Reading
database ... 65% (Reading database ... 70% (Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80% (Reading database ... 85% (Reading database
... 90% (Reading database ... 95% (Reading database ... 100% (Reading
database ... 195378 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking ruby-json-pure (from
.../ruby-json-pure_1.5.1-0ubuntu3_all.deb) ... dpkg: error processing
/var/cache/apt/archives/ruby-json-pure_1.5.1-0ubuntu3_all.deb
(--unpack):  trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/json.rb',
which is also in package ruby-json 1.6.3-1 No apport report written
because MaxReports is reached already Errors were encountered while
processing: 
/var/cache/apt/archives/ruby-json-pure_1.5.1-0ubuntu3_all.deb Error in
function:  dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of
ruby-vmc:  ruby-vmc depends on ruby-json-pure (>= 1.5.1); however:  
Package ruby-json-pure is not installed. dpkg: error processing
ruby-vmc (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of
cloudfoundry-client:  cloudfoundry-client depends on ruby-vmc (=
0.3.10-0ubuntu10); however:   Package ruby-vmc is not configured yet. dpkg: error processing cloudfoundry-client (--configure):  dependency
problems - leaving unconfigured
```

How can fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to install the latest Vagrant .deb from their website. It transitioned away from being a Ruby gem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that one of Vagrant's dependencies requires the package `ruby-json-pure` to be installed. However, that is conflicting with the package `ruby-json` which is already installed. You could try removing the package `ruby-json`, but that might require you to remove whatever installed it in the first place.

I don't think there is an easy solution to this; it looks like it has been reported as a bug and is fixed in Quantal and above:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ruby-vmc/+bug/1045460